# Overriding parent prototype method for event handling

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am using the following code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMF5e/1/) to work with form fields and events. I have previously asked two questions regarding this and they have helped me tremendously. Now I have a new problem/question.

```
function Field(args) {
    this.id = args.id;

    this.elem = document.getElementById(this.id);
    this.value = this.elem.value;
}

Field.prototype.addEvent = function (type) {
    this.elem.addEventListener(type, this, false);
};

// FormTitle is the specific field like a text field. There could be many of them.
function FormTitle(args) {
    Field.call(this, args);
}

Field.prototype.blur = function (value) {
    alert("Field blur");  
};

FormTitle.prototype.blur = function () {
    alert("FormTitle Blur");
};

Field.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    var prop = event.type;
    if ((prop in this) && typeof this[prop] == "function")
        this[prop](this.value);
};

inheritPrototype(FormTitle, Field);
var title = new FormTitle({name: "sa", id: "title"});
title.addEvent('blur');


function inheritPrototype(e, t) {
    var n = Object.create(t.prototype);
    n.constructor = e;
    e.prototype = n
}

if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function (e) {
        function t() {}
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            throw new Error("Object.create implementation only accepts the first parameter.")
        }
        t.prototype = e;
        return new t
   }
}
```

The problem is that I want to override the parent method (`Field.prototype.blur`) and instead use `FormTitle.prototype.blur` method for the title object. But the object keeps referencing the parent method and the alert always shows 'Field blur' instead of 'FormTitle Blur'. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a method in the `FormTitle` prototype, then replacing the whole prototype with another object using `inheritPrototype`.

You have to swap the order. First you call this:

```
inheritPrototype(FormTitle, Field);
```

Then you set onblur on the prototype object you just created:

```
FormTitle.prototype.blur = function () {
    alert("FormTitle Blur");
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zMF5e/2/

Comment: Aha! That makes sense a lot. By the way, is prototypal inheritance a good match for events/form-fields handling? Or am I doing it wrong entirely?

Comment: It's not wrong at all, in fact I like that style of coding. Just keep in mind that addEventListener and handleEvent won't work in IE8 and below.

Comment: Thanks much, and yes, I added the compatibility code from MDN to cover that.